# How do I return an Input from one method to the other without using a global variable and without the input being asked again in java

Tags: java, javafx

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter A to Add Customer\nEnter V to View Customers");
    System.out.print("Enter Your Option : ");
    String option = input.next();
    getInput(option);
    Application.launch(args);
}
public void start(Stage stage) {
    stage.setTitle("Train Booking System");
    Scene window = makeButtons();
    stage.setScene(window);
    stage.show();
}
public static String getInput(String Input){
    return Input;
}
public static Scene makeButtons() {
    GridPane layout = new GridPane();
    Scene window = new Scene(layout, 1366, 768);
    for (int column = 1; column <= 10; column++) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        layout.add(btn, column, column);
        btn.setId("btn");
        Button finalBtn = btn;
        if (getInput().equals("A"))
            btn.setOnAction(e -> {
                finalBtn.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #FF3EA5FF");
            });
        }
    return window;
}
```

I am making a software like to add a booking and I should store it (which I have to do still) , also I have the option to view bookings so in this
case I dont want to be able to click the button.

How do I set the buttons' action in the if condition without getting the input again as the input will be asked again

Comment: Guys im so sorry i made a mistake i will edit this code this is how its supposed to be like

Comment: Just... why? If you're writing a GUI-based application, why would you request user input from the console, instead of from the GUI itself?

Comment: Its cause of the coursework that I am given  my lecturer has mentioned that the menu should be in the console and there are options to add and view booking are in the GUI. On top of this global variables and scenebuilder cant be used :(

Comment: Not using “global” variables makes sense, and from an educational perspective I can see not using scenebuilder makes sense, but using a console for input in a GUI program makes no sense. Are you sure you understood that correctly, and your not supposed to use a menu (across the top of the window, etc)?  But anyway, the obvious way to do it would just be to move the console code to the beginning of the `start()` method.

Comment: I suppose you can also pass the option as part of the `args ` array, but it still makes no sense.

Comment: wait how do i pass it as an option in the args array. sorry if i am disturbing you i am pretty new to java

Comment: Just make it part of the array you pass to `launch()`. You can retrieve it in `start()`, see [the documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Application.html#getParameters())

Comment: Thanks a lot dude and to everyone who helped me out. Thanks for the quick replies.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    showInput(getInput());
}

public static int getInput(){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num = sc.nextInt();
    return num;
}
public static void showInput(int input){
    System.out.println(input);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> How do I return an Input from one method to the other without using a
>   global variable and without the input being asked again in java

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
        int n = getInput();
        showInput(n);
    }

    public static int getInput() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = sc.nextInt();
        return num;
    }

    public static void showInput(int n) {
        System.out.println("The input is " + n);
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter an integer: 10
The input is 10
```

Comment: How would this help? You can't pass an `int` parameter to the `start(Stage)` method.

Comment: @James_D - when I wrote this answer, it fitted the question which was specific to the title, `How do I return an Input from one method to the other without using a global variable and without the input being asked again in java`. Now, I can see that the question has been edited. I need to go through the updated question and I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Ah, OK, apologies; I hadn't looked at the edit history of the question.

Comment: @James_D - no problem. Thanks anyway for your comment because now I can go through the updated question and see how I can help OP.

Comment: The question doesn't really make sense, IMHO; if this is a JavaFX (GUI) application, why would the OP be asking for user input from the command line, instead of in the GUI itself. But if you think it's worth answering... feel free.

Comment: No cause like i have a coursework and my lecturer made some restrictions he was like no global variables and the menu is in console if you could help i will appreciate

Comment: He also said scenebuilder can't be used so I was a bit confused and I am still in my first  year tbh the coursework is really hard

Comment: @James_D - I can see that someone downvoted my answer and co-incidentally it was when you posted your comment. If it is you who downvoted it, I request you to cancel your downvote as you know why I answered like this.

Comment: I canceled it after your reply to my comment. Not sure if there was another downvote.

Comment: @James_D - Thanks. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Just pass it as parameter:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int in=getInput();
    showInput(i);
}
public static int getInput(){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num = sc.nextInt();
    return num;
}
public static void showInput(int i){
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

This saves the input into a **local** variable that is only valid inside the `main` method.

Also, the `showInput` method gets an `int` value as parameter so it does not need to load it by itself.

Or, you can pass the return value directly:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    showInput(getInput());
}
```

This skips saving the input in a variable and passes it directly.

Note that both ways are essentially the same.

Also note that you should `close()` the `Scanner` when you don't need it anymore. This will be important if you handle streams other than `System.in`.

Closing means saying you won't need a resource any more and giving it away to the operating system.

But if you `close()` a `Scanner`, the resource it is built on will also be closed.

That means, you won't be able to use `System.in` after this again. You may want to have one `Scanner` that is instantiated and closed in the `main` method and passed to the `getInput()` method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int in=getInput(sc);
    showInput(i);
    sc.close();
}
public static int getInput(Scanner sc){
    int num = sc.nextInt();
    return num;
}
public static void showInput(int i){
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Or(even better but you that is more advanced) with a try-with-resources:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try(Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in)){
        int in=getInput(sc);
        showInput(i);
    }
}
public static int getInput(Scanner sc){
    int num = sc.nextInt();
    return num;
}
public static void showInput(int i){
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

If you don't want the `Scanner` to be instantiated in the main method, you can create a new method for this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try(Scanner sc=getScanner()){
        int in=getInput(sc);
        showInput(i);
    }
}
public static Scanner getScanner(){
    return new Scanner(System.in);
}
public static int getInput(Scanner sc){
    int num = sc.nextInt();
    return num;
}
public static void showInput(int i){
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 **Sure do this**
public class Test {
public static int getInput(){
    System.out.println("enter a number");
    return new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
}
public static void showInput(int number){
    System.out.println(number);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    showInput(getInput());
}
}
```